# Short-selling domestic currency to hedge against inflation

Tags: inflation, exchange-rates, insurance

A person lives in a country with a high risk of inflation. She just started working, so she has little savings. Her goal is to ensure that her future income does not lose value because of inflation. Because of regulations, she cannot buy shares or bonds from any country (I can provide details if it seems unrealistic). Is it a good idea for her to short-sell domestic currency? She could do that by borrowing domestic currency and using it all to buy dollars. If the domestic currency depreciates, her future income is worth less, but she gains from short-selling. Otherwise, she loses from short-selling, but her future income is worth more. Assuming she is risk-averse, she should go for this option.

Comment: That's not risk averse. That's akin to gambling. Where exactly can you take a loan to just buy a foreign currency but not invest in stocks of bonds? If the FX rate moves in the wrong direction you can quickly become unable to repay the loan. This is also not an economics question.

Comment: The interest on the loan is going to be a bit higher than the expected inflation rate. For example if the currency value usually halves every year, and I borrow \$1000 now, I have to pay back \$2100 next year because the lender isn't stupid.